# How to get Parent page URL by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a scenario where Im opening a modal window dailog from Page1.aspx. Now after opening the modal window dialog If a user copies a URL and tries to open that window dialog directly from the browser. The modal window dialog shouldn't open directly. It should open ONLY from Page1.aspx. How do I check if user has not opened it directly in the browser. Basically Im looking for a substitute of URLReferrer in javascript.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks & regards,

Sumit Arora

Comment: Did you check document.location.href? It returns the current page. If that does not contain page1.aspx, you know it's not opened from that page.

Comment: Hi Baszz, document.location.href gives the URL of the Modal Window Dialog page instead of the parent page.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the parent with `window.parent`.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly to using this line of script

```
if(window.opener)
  {
   var locationOfParentWin =  window.opener.location.href;
  }
```

Regards

Comment: please mark my ansewer as a correct one if it is useful to you :)